# Deserialize json string with multiple objects

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I have the following JSON response after calling an API:

```
{
   "Item": "Some value",
   "Status": "ST",
   "Details": "something here...",
   "TargetObject": [
      {
         "Value1": "1",
         "Value2": [
            {
               "ABC1": "......",
               "ABC2": "...",
               "ABC3": "..."
            }
         ],
         "Value3": [
            {
               "ABCD1": "......",
               "ABCD2": "...",
               "ABCD3": [
                  {
                     "ABCVal": "123"
                  },
                  {
                     "Extra": "123"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

What I want to do is to return the values from **TargetObject** but this key has more than one objects/arrays inside so my question is: how can I return only those values and print the following JSON result:

```
{
   "TargetObject": [
      { 
        "Value1": "1",
        "Value2": [
           {
              "ABC1": "......",
              "ABC2": "...",
              "ABC3": "..."
           }
        ],
        "Value3": [
           {
              "ABCD1": "......",
              "ABCD2": "...",
              "ABCD3": [
                 {
                    "ABCVal": "123"
                 },
                 {
                    "Extra": "123"
                 }
              ]
           }
        ]
     }
   ]
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
public async Task<List<List<MyModel>>> GetAsync(string url)
{
    /*
        Code to get the above JSON
    */
    
    //Trying to return the expected JSON
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<MyModel>>>(jsonString);
}
```

And this is my Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string TargetObject { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string ABC1 { get; set; }
    public string ABC2 { get; set; }
    public string ABC3 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
    public string ABCD1 { get; set; }
    public string ABCD2 { get; set; }
    public string ABCD3 { get; set; }
    public string ABCVal { get; set; }
    public string Extra { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment I'm getting the following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[myProjectNamespace.Models.MyModel]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Use something like [json to C#](https://json2csharp.com/)  or [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/) to build out your class definitions to support your json. You'll also notice why you have that exception.

Comment: How "dynamic" is your json, because its one thing to support a `Dictionary<string,string>` for something like `Value2` but to have any key/value supported is somewhat harder

Answer (score 0):

What about dynamic object?

```
     public async Task<dynamic> GetAsync(string url)
     {
      /*
          Code to get the above JSON
      */     
      return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
     }
```

PS: install Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: This solves the error message but the JSON printed is blank, only has the characters { [ but null values

Comment: just call a property it will show something.

Answer (score 0):

If you have strongly typed JSON then you need to create a few models (DTO) to represent a structure of the JSON. Note: `ABCD3` has different types in `Value2` and `Value3`, you should define it by yourself according to your data

```
public class Root
{
    public List<TargetObject> TargetObject { get; set; } 
}
public class TargetObject
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; } 
    public List<Value2> Value2 { get; set; } 
    public List<Value3> Value3 { get; set; } 
}
public class Value2
{
    public string ABC1 { get; set; } 
    public string ABC2 { get; set; } 
    public string ABC3 { get; set; } 
}
public class Value3
{
    public string ABCD1 { get; set; } 
    public string ABCD2 { get; set; } 
    public List<ABCD3> ABCD3 { get; set; } 
}
public class ABCD3
{
    public string ABCVal { get; set; } 
    public string Extra { get; set; } 
}
```

then

```
 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```

In case when you need just to get content of `TargetObject` as a `string`, use:

```
var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);
var targetObject = jsonDoc.RootElement.GetProperty("TargetObject").GetRawText();
```

Comment: I'm trying the second solution but I'm getting the following error message: The requested operation requires an element of type 'Object', but the target element has type 'Array'

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what do you need? It should be a typed object, or it is ok to get it as a string? It'll let me direction how to edit my answer

Comment: What you do in your first answer it's okay, I'm just seeing if the second one also works for me. The error message is solved. The response was adding [ ] at the beginning and at the end of the JSON.

Comment: Ok then, if you need to implement the first case, be careful with types as I described in notes in the answer.